# Where does the XXX comment prefix in Eclipse come from?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

I was just wandering why is the prefix `XXX` ?

As far as I know its used for notes/reminders (or at least this is what I use it for and that is what the people on most of the links I googled use it for).

So does anyone know where the `XXX` prefix come from ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [Hacker's Dictionary entry for "XXX"](http://www.outpost9.com/reference/jargon/jargon_39.html#TAG2023):

> A marker that attention is needed.
>   Commonly used in program comments to
>   indicate areas that are kluged up or
>   need to be. Some hackers liken `XXX'
>   to the notional heavy-porn movie
>   rating. Compare [FIXME](http://www.outpost9.com/reference/jargon/jargon_21.html#TAG637).

Answer (score 28):

From Sun/Oracle's [Java code conventions, section 10.5.4:](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-137265.html#395)

> Use XXX in a comment to flag something that is bogus but works. Use FIXME to flag something that is bogus and broken.

Answer (score 9):

`XXX`, along with `FIXME` and `TODO`, is known in Eclipse as a task tag, and is indexed by the IDE to let you find the spots marked with those tags easily. You can edit such tags in the Eclipse Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Task Tags.

As to where it comes from: it probably emerged form the "tags" that programmers spontaneously wrote in their code to quickly mark a given line. While FIXME and TODO are explicit enough, the reason XXX was used could be a combination of these reasons:

- The string "XXX" does not usually occur in regular source code and is easy to look for with tools such as grep or a simple text search in an editor;
- Traditionally, "X marks the spot" which needs attention; triple X even more so;
- The X key is very close to the Command/Alt/Windows keys and is easy to reach, being on the lower row of the keyboard.

I can't think of anything else...

Answer (score 4):

Various reasons:

1. It's easy to search for.
2. No collision, as no sane person would use it as a variable.
3. It can used to mark code that needs e**X**tra special attention, dangerous code, not to be seen by underaged, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I've worked with a team where `XXX` was used to point out a "bug or task that was not yet entered in Trac.".  After it was entered in Trac the comment would be changed to `TODO` with the ID appended.

To Eclipse though, it's just a marker like `TODO` and `FIXME`.  I imagine that it's originally used as a strong form of `TODO`.  You usually see comments like this:

```
// TODO: Need to optimize this once n becomes greater than 1000.
```

But sometimes you'll have a comment like:

```
// TODO: Fix SQL injection bug before production release!
```

Unfortunately a quick `grep` wont make that SQL injection bug stand out among the 1000s of other `TODO`s.  Using XXX here would help mark things that must be done before a milestone/release etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a reference to it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_%28computer_programming%29#Tags):

> XXX to warn other programmers of problematic or misguiding code.

Answer (score 0):

It bugs me too, because *XXX* may also be used for masking input or format numbers,

Thus creating multi markers warning when you describe amount format:

```
/**
 * @param amount (XXX or XXX.XX)
 */
public doSomething(String amount) {
```

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> -XXX or
>
> -XXX.XX)

As @Jean-PhilippePellet suggested, you can remove it from

> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Task Tags