# Why "XXX" word in Java comment in eclipse IDE take a special style?

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, comments

When i write a Java comment in Eclipse IDE containning "XXX" word
Like that

```
// Increment 
// XXX => Not like that [ x = x++; ]
// OK  => BUT like that [ x++; ]
```

The "XXX" word take a style which is different a normal comment style
Its color will be (Blue color) NOT (Green color)

Note
"XXX" comment color is like that "TODO" comment color
Like

```
// XXX color like TODO color
```

Why that ?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388292/how-do-i-enable-todo-fixme-xxx-task-tags-in-eclipse

Comment: Have a look in the code style settings; It's been a while since I used Eclipse, but somewhere in there TODO, FIXME and XXX is declared "special" when used in comments.

Comment: http://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/vhdl/Reminders_TODO_Markers.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456560/where-does-the-xxx-comment-prefix-in-eclipse-come-from

Comment: See here:
[stack overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456560/where-does-the-xxx-comment-prefix-in-eclipse-come-from

So it is mostly for historical reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XXX is sometimes used as a tag for bugs or other bad stuff. Eclipse recognises various kinds of tags in comments, and highlights them. TODO and FIXME are other examples that spring to mind.

It's configured under Java > Compiler > Task Tags in the preferences.

A way to make use of this is with the Tasks view; this lists all the occurrences of such tags in your code, and lets you jump to them. It's handy as a super-lightweight micro-task tracking system.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you can define special words that have a meaning. `XXX` is defined in the same place as the `TODO` word, it's an Eclipse default, but you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

> A marker that attention is needed. Commonly used in program comments to indicate areas that are kluged up or need to be. Some hackers liken `XXX' to the notional heavy-porn movie rating. Compare FIXME.

[Quoted from the Jargon File](http://www.outpost9.com/reference/jargon/jargon_39.html#TAG2023)

Answer (score 0):

`XXX` is used as a task tag in eclipse for comments, it has a priority of normal. Other tags include `TODO` (Normal), `FIXME` (High). It can be used to mark section of your code that need attention, later review and also communicate what should be done, some of these are tasks you would like to handle at a later stage. More [here](http://pipecuts.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/eclipse-task-tags-meaning/)